# Why do we need the tensor name

Tags: tensorflow

Imagine I have a layer I want to repeat K times:

```
    {conv - relu - pool} x K
```

In that case I need to iteratively run the forward pass for K-th layer:

```
for k in range(len(K)):
    Wk = ...
    bk = ...
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool, Wk, ...) + bk
```

Here if I miss 'name' parameter - will my conv tensor be replaced on every iteration? Would the correct variant be:

```
for k in range(len(K)):
    Wk = ...
    bk = ...
    name='conv%d' % (k)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(name=name, pool, Wk, ...) + bk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you don't put a name, IT DOESN'T OVERWRITE or replace the value. TF comes up with its own naming convention like const_1, const_2, etc.

At least one of the reasons name parameter helps is because TensorBoard uses that. This parameter is used in TF namespace (vs Python namespace - hence the variable name is ignored by TF).

So, when you have multiple iterations, that naming convention will be used to name different names.

WRT how to use it, there are few ways of doing this -one of them you already typed. Another way is to use "scope" - so that your TB (TensorBoard) graphs look much neater and manageable. Using scope is also optional at least from TB perspective.